# Could the power series still converge?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Assume that $a>0, \mu > 0$ and look at the complex function

$$f(z)\doteq \exp\left(-a(\sqrt{\mu^2-2z}-\mu)\right).$$

From what I understand we need a branch of the logarithm for the square root to be defined? So we can define this function for $\Re(z)<\mu^2/2$?

Now let $x_0<0$ be a real number. We then have that $f(z)$ has a power series around $x_0$ so that here

$$f(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k (z-x_0)^k.$$

Now, I think we can assume that all $a_k$ are real since $f$ resitriced to the real line is a real function, and hence must have real derivatives?

So we can look at the powerseries where the argument is real

$$g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k (x-x_0)^k.$$

**My question is: Is it possible that the power series $g(x)$ converges for  $x = \mu^2/2$? or $x > \mu^2/2$?**

**Attempt:**
In order to disprove this I think I must show that $f$ can not have an holomorphic extension to an area where $\Re(z)>\mu^2/2$, is this correct? Because then if $g$ then converges then $g$ would be holomorphic and hence we have a contradiction? Is there a way to prove that $f$ can not have an holomorphic extension to an area where $\Re(z)>\mu^2/2$?

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you taking complex analysis, and if so, have you reached the part of the course where you prove that if $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z_0$, then the power series of $f$ about $z_0$ converges in the largest disk centered at $z_0$ to which $f$ extends holomorphically?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I took complex analysis some years ago, now I am just trying to use it in another context. But I went back in my book and I saw the result you are talking about.

Comment: Under the circumstances, it's reasonable to answer your own question. :)